# Save multiple Seekbar sharedpreferences

Tags: android, save, sharedpreferences, seekbar

I've got an Activity where y have 3 seekbar and I see each seekbar's value on each seekbar's textview.

Now, I want to store each seekbar's value with sharedPreferences. I've tryed it in several ways, but i'm not able to get it.

I've readed that the corret way to do it is to save the values when calling onPause, and to restore them when calling onResume.

```
public class Configuration extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    public TextView progress1;
    public TextView progress2;
    public TextView progress3;
    private SeekBar bar1;
    private SeekBar bar2;
    private SeekBar bar3;

    private int savedProgress1;
    private int savedProgress2;
    private int savedProgress3; 
    private int loadedProgress1;
    private int loadedProgress2;
    private int loadedProgress3;
    private String Key_PROGRESS_1 = "bar1_progress";
    private String Key_PROGRESS_2 = "bar2_progress";
    private String Key_PROGRESS_3 = "bar3_progress";

    SharedPreferences mPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;



    /*********************
     * 
     * ONCREATE
     * 
     ********************/


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.configuracion2);



        bar1 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.fast_bar); //make seekbar object
        bar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);   //set seekbar listener 
        progress1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.salida1);

        bar2 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.climb_bar);
        bar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);      
        progress2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.salida2);

        bar3 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.platform_bar);
        bar3.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);      
        progress3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.salida3);


        mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        editor = mPreferences.edit();



    }


    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        Log.v("", "" + bar);
        switch (bar.getId()) {  
            case R.id.fast_bar:
                progress1.setText(progress + "%");
                break;
            case R.id.climb_bar:
                progress2.setText(progress + "%");
                break;
            case R.id.platform_bar:
                progress3.setText(progress + "%");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {     
    }   
     @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(seekBar.getProgress());    
    }




     protected void onResume() {    
         super.onResume();

             loadedProgress1 = mPreferences.getInt("Key_PROGRESS_1", 0);
             bar1.setProgress(loadedProgress1);         

             loadedProgress2 = mPreferences.getInt("Key_PROGRESS_2", 0);
             bar2.setProgress(loadedProgress2);

             loadedProgress2 = mPreferences.getInt("Key_PROGRESS_3", 0);
             bar3.setProgress(loadedProgress3);

     }




     protected void onPause(/*SeekBar seekBar*/) {
        super.onPause();

                savedProgress1 = bar1.getProgress();
                editor.putInt(Key_PROGRESS_1, savedProgress1);
                savedProgress2 = bar2.getProgress();
                editor.putInt(Key_PROGRESS_2, savedProgress2);
                savedProgress3 = bar3.getProgress();
                editor.putInt(Key_PROGRESS_3, savedProgress3);
                editor.commit();


     }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't keep the same `SharedPreferences.Editor` object as a private member.

Call `mPreferences.edit()` inside `onPause()`:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
savedProgress1 = bar1.getProgress();
editor.putInt(Key_PROGRESS_1, savedProgress1);
savedProgress2 = bar2.getProgress();
editor.putInt(Key_PROGRESS_2, savedProgress2);
savedProgress3 = bar3.getProgress();
editor.putInt(Key_PROGRESS_3, savedProgress3);
editor.commit();
```

---

Also, it can't work because you're using the string `"Key_PROGRESS_X"` instead of the variable `Key_PROGRESS_X`, in your `onResume()` method.